# how to fix this loop that goes through brackets in a expr

Tags: python, recursion

The idea isfind the first closing bracket then remove the from the input from the last open bracket.

Ive tried recursion but dont really understand it.

```
def complex_evaluation(tokens):
    brackets = ["(", "[", "{", ")", "]", "}"]
    bracketsclose = [")", "]", "}"]
    bracketsopen = ["(", "[", "{"]
    brackpos = []
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        if tokens[i] in brackets:
            brackpos.append([tokens[i], i])
    while len(brackpos) != 0:
        last = brackpos[0][1]
        for i in brackpos:
            if i[0] in bracketsclose:
                x = simple_evaluation(tokens[last + 1:i[1]])
                del tokens[last:i[1] + 1]
                tokens.insert(last, x)
            last = i[1]
            print(tokens)


complex_evaluation([2, "^", "[", 4, "*", "(", 4, "+", 5, ")", "]", "/", 4])
```

expected result should be a result that has no brackets.

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: "expected result should be a result that has no brackets." So the expected result is `[2, "^", "/", 4]`? Or is it "find the first closing bracket then remove the from the input from the last open bracket.", so `[2, "^", "[", 4, "*", "]", "/", 4]`?

Comment: [Shunting-yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: well it should at the end be a single evulation for example 4+9

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question right, I think you can achieve this:

> expected result should be a result that has no brackets.

In a better way. You can do the following:

```
brackets = ["(", "[", "{", ")", "]", "}"]
result = [x for x in tokens if not x in brackets]

>>> result 
[2, '^', 4, '*', 4, '+', 5, '/', 4]
```

Logic: if an item is in both 'tokens' and also 'brackets' lists, then ignore it, otherwise add it to our result list.